# DipStick shows upper limit even before recommended amount of oil is poured

Tags: honda, oil, scooter

My Honda activa scooter's manual say to add 800 ml of engine oil when the strainer screen is cleaned.I have drained all the oil and cleaned the strainer screen. I bought 800 ml pack of manufacture's recommended oil but when I poured new oil and checked the dipstick it showed the oil level at upper level even before I poured entire content from the oil bottle.I mean still there is around 100 ml of oil left in the bottle and the dipstick already shows upper level mark.Should I still continue to add the left over oil from the bottle or follow the dipstick ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the engine, stop it, wait a few minutes and check again - there may be internal reservoirs that need filling : voids, pipes etc

Comment: I already did it.I have ridden about 100 kms after that but it is still the same

Comment: Are you certain you drained ALL the oil, or just MOST of it - did you actually measure how much came out... If the level is correct at the moment, then it should be fine.

Comment: yes i am sure that I drained out all the oil from the engine.I kept the drain bolt open for around 2 hours unplugged and even tilted my scooter to pour all the bad oil out.As you suggested i have even measured the drained out oil from the sump.It is around 700 ml(the expected quantity from the user manual)

Comment: If you took out 700ml then why do you expect to refill with 800ml ?

Comment: Thats' what the manual say and I think that makes a sense also since after 4000 kms of  drain interval around 100 ml of oil might get consumed in form of leakages or miscellaneous reasons don't you think the same?

Comment: But you top up between the drain intervals...........

Comment: Yes I agree but I did not top it up during that interval

Comment: So, if the oil was at the correct level, then you drain out 700ml, then you refill with 700ml it will return to the correct level. So, how, really, do you expect to take out 700 and put back 800?

Comment: Yes that's what my question is since user manual say to add 800 ml of oil

Comment: You say the expected quantity is 700ml from the user manual, but you also say the quantity is 800ml also from the user manual - what are you reading / not reading correctly in the manual?

Comment: I said that 700ml of oil is the expected quantity for the oil that is drained from the sump and 800 ml is the recommended qty for the new oil that needs to be poured into the oil sump

Comment: Perhaps the difference in the quantities is down to whether the filter is changed or not.

Answer (score 4):

As @SolarMike says in his comment - you probably didn't get all of the old oil out when you drained it, so there was probably some already in there before you started adding it from the bottle.

Keep the last 100ml for topping up later - as long as the level in the engine is between the marks you'll be fine.